# #markup is replacing colon in <gcse:search... tag with space

Tags: theming, 8

I have the following code:

```
 return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<gcse:search queryParameterName="query" resultsUrl="'
        . Url::fromRoute('cn.search', [], ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString()
        . '"></gcse:search>',
      '#allowed_tags' => ['gcse', 'gcse:search'],
    );
```

but the output is:

```
  <gcse search queryparametername="query" resultsurl="http://d8.constitutionnet.org/search2"></gcse>
```

How do I prevent the colon being converted to a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inline template:

```
  return [
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => '<gcse:search queryParameterName="query" resultsUrl="{{ url }}"></gcse:search>',
    '#context' => [
      'url' => Url::fromRoute('cn.search', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]),
    ],
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks @4k4, but is the fact that `'#allowed_tags' => ['gcse', 'gcse:search']` doesn't work a bug?

Comment: #allowed_tags is more for simple tags. If you put such complex html in a template or at least in an inline template, your module is also nice to themers, because they are able to change the template and/or the variables separately.